# How to get the Uniq objects Using javascript or lodash

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js, lodash

i am having the Array of objects like this

```
    var result={
            "employees": [
        {
            "_id": "5796e7a27d075bd0453b7751",
            "firstName": "Test4",
            "schemaName": "Employee"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5796e78e7d075bd0453b774f",
            "firstName": "Test 3",
            "schemaName": "Employee"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5790b203df5ad69025e8a20b",
            "email": "df@gmail.com",
            "schemaName": "Employee"
        },
        {
            "_id": "577f69cc789df5ec1e995513",
            "firstName": "Jeevan",
            "email": "ddd@asd.com",
            "schemaName": "Employee"
        },
        {
            "_id": "577f69cc789df5ec1e995513",
            "firstName": "Chethan",
            "email": "ddd@asd.com",
            "schemaName": "Employee"
        }
    ]
};
    };
```

but i want uniq objects by email. i am using lodash uniq but its Not giving proper Result. here  i tried this code.

```
var combined=result.employees.map(function(employee){
    employee.schemaName='Employee';
    return employee;
});
combined = _.uniq(combined, 'email');
console.log(combined);
```

The Result is coming like this.

```
   [ { _id: '5796e7a27d075bd0453b7751',
    firstName: 'Test4',
    schemaName: 'Employee' },
  { _id: '5790b203df5ad69025e8a20b',
    email: 'df@gmail.com',
    schemaName: 'Employee' },
  { _id: '577f69cc789df5ec1e995513',
    firstName: 'Jeevan',
    email: 'ddd@asd.com',
    schemaName: 'Employee' } ]
```

i want the objects which are not having email ids and i want only objects which are unique emailid's can anybody help me on this. I want the Result contain the objects Which are not having email id also. The Result should be like this.

```
[ { _id: '5796e7a27d075bd0453b7751',
    firstName: 'Test4',
    schemaName: 'Employee' },
{ _id: '5796e78e7d075bd0453b774f',
    firstName: 'Test3',
    schemaName: 'Employee' },
  { _id: '5790b203df5ad69025e8a20b',
    email: 'df@gmail.com',
    schemaName: 'Employee' },
  { _id: '577f69cc789df5ec1e995513',
    firstName: 'Jeevan',
    email: 'ddd@asd.com',
    schemaName: 'Employee' } ]
```

Comment: please give an example what the overall result should look like

Comment: Unique is working correctly. you have one object for email undefined, and one object of every other email that your have in your set. As Arif said, If you provide the expected result we can help you with how to get it.

Comment: Do you mean you don't want the objects without email to be merged?

Comment: @Arif   ya i have updated Result please Check.

Comment: @Roque i want objects without email also to be merged

Comment: @Reza i provided the Expected Result Please Check.

Comment: Why are `Test 4` , `Test 3` included in result?

Comment: @guest271314 i want the objects Which are Not having Email ids also has to be merged in the Result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could make it too.

```
_.uniqBy(result.employees, function(employee){return employee.email || employee._id;});
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend the use of [_.uniqWith](https://lodash.com/docs#uniqWith) for this with your own comparator.

```js
var result = {
    "employees": [
        {
            "_id": "5796e7a27d075bd0453b7751",
            "firstName": "Test4",
            "lastName": "T",
            "__v": 0,
            "schemaName": "Employee"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5796e78e7d075bd0453b774f",
            "firstName": "Test 3",
            "lastName": "T",
            "__v": 0,
            "schemaName": "Employee"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5796e77e7d075bd0453b774d",
            "firstName": "Test 2",
            "lastName": "T",
            "__v": 0,
            "documents": [],
            "schemaName": "Employee"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5796e7707d075bd0453b774b",
            "firstName": "Test1",
            "lastName": "T",
            "__v": 0,
            "schemaName": "Employee"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5790b203df5ad69025e8a20b",
            "firstName": "Ganesh",
            "lastName": "dsf",
            "__v": 0,
            "email": "df@gmail.com",
            "schemaName": "Employee"
        },
        {
            "_id": "577f69cc789df5ec1e995513",
            "firstName": "Jeevan",
            "__v": 0,
            "email": "fs@asf.com",
            "schemaName": "Employee"
        },
        {
            "_id": "577f69cc789df5ec1e995513",
            "firstName": "Chethan",
            "__v": 0,
            "email": "fs@asf.com",
            "schemaName": "Employee"
        }
    ]
};

// Create a lodash chain from the employees.
combined = _.uniqWith(result.employees, function(e1, e2){
  return e1.email && e1.email === e2.email;
});

console.log(combined);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.14.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Rouque thanks for your answer. do we have any other option to do this. i am using lodash 3.10 its not Supporting this _.uniqWith function. i dont have permission to update the lodash so.

Comment: In that case @season's answer looks appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a `deepEquals` algorithm so this code becomes more general. If you want to check only by email, just change the `equals` function below.

```js
const equals =
  // Naïve deepEquals, only for demo. Doesn't work if keys orders vary.
  (obj1, obj2) => JSON.stringify(obj1) === JSON.stringify(obj2);

  // A real deepEquals:
  // https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-deep-equal

const uniq = (el1, index1, array) =>
  array.every((el2, index2) => index1 <= index2 || !equals(el1, el2));

[{ a: 1, b: 2 }, { c: 3 }, { a: 1, b: 2 }, { d: 4 }, { a: 1, b: 2 }].filter(uniq);
// Result: [ { a: 1, b: 2 }, { c: 3 }, { d: 4 } ]
```